# is there a formula to transpose one cell based on another

Tags: formula, array-formulas

If T2= "5"

then

A2(on a different sheet)= N2,

B2(on different sheet)= N2,

C2(on different sheet)= N2,

D2(on different sheet)= N2,

E2(on different sheet)= N2

then

if T3= "2"

F2(on different sheet)=N2

G2(on different sheet)=N2

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 formulas for this:

1. Only T2=5 or and T2 = 3 get give five, three, eight or zero columns will be N2

   ```
   ={if(MainSheet!T2=5,{MainSheet!N2,MainSheet!N2,MainSheet!N2,MainSheet!N2,MainSheet!N2},{"","","","",""}),if(MainSheet!T3=2,{MainSheet!N2,MainSheet!N2},{"",""})}
   ```
2. T2+T3 columns will be N2

   ```
   =split(rept(MainSheet!N2 & ",",MainSheet!T2+MainSheet!T3),",",true,true)
   ```
3. T2 in 5 columns will be N2 and T3 after first 5 columns will be N2

   ```
   =split({rept(MainSheet!N2 & ",",MainSheet!T2) & rept(",",5-MainSheet!T2) & rept(MainSheet!N2 & ",",MainSheet!T3) & rept(",",2-MainSheet!T3)},",",true,false)
   ```